# Return Promise from a recursive call

Tags: javascript, recursion, promise

So, this is admittedly a pretty stupid case I'm describing, but the code I'm working with is doing it and I'm either rewriting it now or find a way to deal with it.
The flow my question refers to looks as follows:

Function A calls Function B. Then, after being called by Function A, Function B calls itself. Then, inside this recursive call, function B calls function C. Function C returns a promise.

What I want to do is "propagating" the promise returned by function C all the way up to function A. 
I already got the syntax to do it in theory, but I don't know if this is actually possible especially with this recursive call by function B.

I just want to know if this is possible and if so, how I can do it. I can understand if you find this very aweful and so do I, but I have to work with it somehow and I'd like to spare me overhauling this code entirely unless there is no other option.

EDIT: Here is the code, I put in some very big spaces around the crucial parts of the code, so it is easier for you to find what you are looking for.

```js
async function getTable(start, ende, liebraum)
{


   $.post("../include/returnTable.php", {
    anfang: start,
    ende: ende,
    art: art
  }).then((data) => {
                      document.getElementById("tablediv").innerHTML = data
                     })
  //return promiseToBeReturnedFromGetTable;
  return fillRooms(liebraum);
}



async function fillRooms(liebraum)
{
    var bool = false
    if (!bool)
    {
     bool = !bool;
     fillRooms(liebraum);
    }
  else
  {
      return Disablen(liebraum);
  }



 async function Disablen(liebraum)
 {
   if(usecase1)
   {
    return $.post('../include/getSitzOptions.php',{
          raum: tisch,
           art: art,
     start: anfang,
     ende: ende
        }).then((data) => {
                $('#sitz').html(data);
                })
   }
   else if(usecase2)
   {
    return $.post('../include/getSitzOptions.php',{
          raum: tisch,
           art: art,
     tagStart: tagAnfang,
     tagEnde: tagEnde
        }).then((data) =>{
                $('#sitz').html(data);
                })
   }
   else if(usecase3)
   {
    return $.post('../include/getSitzOptions.php',{
          raum: tisch,
           art: art,
     WeekStart: WochenStart,
     WeekEnd: WochenEnde
        }).then((data) => {
                $('#sitz').html(data);
                })
   }

  }

}
```

Comment: Yes, very possible, can you post your code?

Comment: Yeah just give me a moment

Comment: Certainly possible, but bear in mind function A & B will also want to be promises, or at least pass promises down the chain.  Great thing is nowadays using `async / await` recursive Promises is no different to none async recursion, with the added bonus you kind of get tail recursion thrown in for free.

Comment: First function doesn't make much sense, the `$.post` is unreachable, and why would you `return await`? Just return the `Promise` alone. Can you trim it down to a [MCVE]? (182 lines is a bit much)

Comment: yeah I'll try to trim it down sry. The "getTable" function returns the promise to another function which MUST wait for the cascade started by getTable to finish. 

I returned await because I didn't knew better, I'm pretty new to promises and my job is to implement async/await where before setTimeout was used to manually synchronize the flow...^^

Comment: Making code unreachable by misplacing a `return` has nothing to do with Promises.

Comment: @CertainPerformance
I corrected my mistake with return making the first $.post unreachable (I accidentally did so when placing the code here).
 also made formatting better etc..
Keiths example is still much better than what I've posted here, but to illustrate my description, I hope it still helps a little.

Comment: `async` without `await`? What is that for? Why use `then` when you can use `await`?

Comment: I downvoted this question because the code formatting is terrible and wastes readers' time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Understanding your code and what your trying to do is a little tricky.

But using your description.->

> Function A calls Function B. Then, after being called by Function A,
>   Function B calls itself. Then, inside this recursive call, function B
>   calls function C. Function C returns a promise.

I've created a working snippet that does the above, but for a simple countdown timer.  Of course this is a bit complicated for just a countdown timer, but was hopefully a way of show how A calls B, B calls itself, that in the end return's C.. :)  phew that's a mouthful.. :)

```js
const delay =ms => new Promise((r, j)=>setTimeout(r, ms));

//Function C returns a promise.
const C = async () => {
  return "Blast off.";
}

//Function B calls itself, 
//function B calls function C
const B = async (count) => {
  console.log(count);
  await delay(500);
  if (count < 1) return C();
  return B(count - 1);
}

//function A calls Function B
const A = async (count) => {
  return B(count);
}

console.log("Start countdown");
A(10).
  then(msg => console.log(msg)).
  catch(e => console.log(e));
```